# TM class for goods and registration

Tags: trademark, classification

[image]

I just look up the term harmonized in TM class what does it stand for?
 I have included the images in which the term "harmonised", "harm", "nice", "idle" and "msg".
please help me to define it.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly your question is. Could you clarify?

Comment: on the right side of image , these term are mentioned above the green tick and green dots

Answer (score 0):

I Googled "tmclass harmonised" and selected [this link](https://euipo.europa.eu/ohimportal/en/harmonised-database) which contains the following:

> The Harmonised Database contains more than 70 000 terms from which our users can select the goods and services for which they seek protection in their trade mark applications. This database is used in the European Union Intellectual Property Office's (EUIPO) online trade mark application forms, the Five-step form and the Advanced form, and is made up of terms that have already been accepted by all national intellectual property offices in the European Union (EU).

It appears to mean that the folks at the various EU country trademark-offices have come to agreement on the use of 70,000 terms and are in harmony with their usage. The items with check marks have been harmonised.

Comment: I slighty edited your answer because the EU merely agreed on using those terms for classifying for which technical areas the trademarks apply. (When you apply for a trademark, e.g. "apple" you say "my trademark applies for "mp3 players, smartphones, etc etc."). Then "smartphone" would be one of those terms. The harmonized terms are typically accepted, though others may be used too. So technically, those aren't trademarks, but classifications for trademarks, which I wanted to highlight with the edit.